# Variable binding in aura/sqlquery when using mysqli_* connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, auraphp

I've got a legacy app that uses `mysqli_*()` functions (actually, it uses `mysql_*()` functions. Gah!). I am using [aura/sqlquery](https://packagist.org/packages/aura/sqlquery) as a SQL query generator. For example:

```
$queryFactory = new Aura\SqlQuery\QueryFactory('mysql');
$select = $queryFactory->newSelect();
$select->from('sometable AS t')
    ->where('t.field1 = 0')
    ->where("t.field2 <> ''");
```

Then we get the raw SQL by casting to string:

```
$sql = (string) $select;
```

Now I want to do do some variable binding in a `where()`:

```
$select->where('t.somefield = ?', $somevalue);
```

When I cast to string, the escaping/binding never seems to be occur. It appears that the binding only takes place when one uses PDO and prepared statements.

Any ideas how to get variable binding in `aura/sqlquery` when using a `mysqli` connection?

Comment: I suppose that a query builder is a requirement and you don't want a solution that works with raw SQL?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I prefer to use a query-builder to deal with complex joins. For example, if a User model has several methods which need several joins, then it's easy to perform those common joins in a single helper method and then pass around the `$select` object. Managing raw SQL text feels cumbersome to me.

Comment: Yes, I see. But still. Your requirement is not clear to me. You need to get a raw SQL only, to be used with mysql_ functions and that's the only option?

Comment: Yep, unless I convert to mysqli (which I should probably do anyway) and use `$mysqli->prepare()`, as you suggest (providing that the PHP ver is high enough, which really *is* out of my immediate control).

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP version is >= 5.6, here is a function that you can use to run a query from aura/sqlquery against mysqli

```
function mysqli_query_params($mysqli, $query, $params, $types = NULL)
{
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($select);
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat('s', count($params));
    $statement->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
}
```

used like this

```
mysqli_query_params($mysqli, $select->getStatement(), $select->getBindValues())
```

Comment: I think `David Weinraub` this is the answer you may need for you are looking to make use of mysqli connection and not pdo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$select->getBindValues()` to get the bind values.

I will say make use of Aura.Sql than pdo for it helps you in certain other cases like `IN ()` query.

Taking an example from readme.

```
// a PDO connection
$pdo = new PDO(...);

// prepare the statment
$sth = $pdo->prepare($select->getStatement());

// bind the values and execute
$sth->execute($select->getBindValues());
```

Let me know in case you need more clarification for the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I understand that I can get those bind values to use with PDO. The issue is how to generate raw SQL that I can use with mysql or mysqli.

Comment: There is no other way I am aware of :( .